Continuity of product of Lie group valued Holder functions
I thought the following property should be "obvious", but am having an astounding amount of trouble finding a slick, or any, proof of the following statement.
Let $g,h : [0,T]  \rightarrow G$ be $C^\alpha$-Holder continuous functions. The pointwise product of curves map $g, h \mapsto gh$, with $(gh)_t := g_t h_t$ is continuous in the Holder topology.
This "should" be true because if you try and embed into a matrix Lie group, you can reduce this to addition and multiplication of Holder functions, which are known to be continuous. But I want this result more generally (and more elegantly) proven.
At first I thought I could appeal to the smoothness of the Lie group product. But this doesn't seem to help.
Note that $G$ is naturally a metric space, so one may talk about Holder continuity.
$$\| g||_{C^\alpha} := \frac{d(g_s, g_t)}{|t-s|^\alpha} < \infty, \quad d_{C^\alpha}(g,h) := ||g^{-1}h||_{C^\alpha}$$
It is helpful to pick the metric $d$ to be either left or right invariant, WLOG left. If you assume bi-invariance, it is quite easy to show $d(g_s h_s, g_t h_t) \leq d(g_s h_s, g_s h_t) + d(g_s h_t, g_t h_t) = d(h_s, h_t) + d(g_s, g_t)$, so at least we know we map to another Holder function.
If you assume left only then $d(g_s h_t, g_t h_t) \neq d(g_s, g_t)$, but I think you can perform a sort of supremum recover the proof. To prove continuity, I figured I'd go back to basics and prove sequential continuity. Given $g^n \rightarrow g, h^n \rightarrow h$ I want to obtain $g^n h^n \rightarrow gh$.
Which by definition means $d_{C^\alpha} (g^nh^n, gh) \rightarrow 0$. I tried a triangle inequality again,
$$d_{C^\alpha} (g^nh^n, gh) \leq d_{C^\alpha} (g^nh^n, g^n h) + d_{C^\alpha} (g^nh, gh)$$
But there are too many terms, I can't control/bound all of them with only left invariance. Is there a smarter way to attempt this?
